# Shortened link with Bitly API, how do I remove the 'http://'?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, bit.ly

I'm currently using the [ruby-bitly gem](https://github.com/rafaeldx7/ruby-bitly) to shorten links in a Rails app; however, the result has an "http://" in front of the bit.ly link. This is not friendly for tweets/other length sensitive posts. How do I automatically remove that?

Link controller action:

```
 def shorten_with_bitly(url)
    link = Link.find(params[:id]) 
    bitly = Bitly.shorten(url, "MY_ID", "MY_API_KEY")
    bitly.url = link.shortened_link
    link.save 
 end
```

Thank you very much for your help!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use gsub, for instance:

```
"http://google.com".gsub("http://", "")
```

or use slice:

```
"http://google.com".slice!(0..6)
```

Keep in mind that the ! will modify the original string, not just give you a modified copy.

Comment: In my examples, I used a string, you'd use link.shortened_url.gsub("http://", "") or the other method.

Comment: awesome! very practical, cant believe i forgot the basics! i feel like back when i started learning python, countless hours slicing tuples haha